# Align text in center of cell next to image in itexsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Here is visual what my problem looks like.

[image: probelm image]

Here is my code that produce that result.

```
public void intervencionHeaderLogo(string pictureURL,int width, int height)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pictureURL));
        image.ScaleAbsolute(width, height);
        image.Alignment = 2;

        //Table
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Reporte de intervención", font);

        //Cell no 1
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.AddElement(p);
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Cell no 2
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.Border = 0;
        cell.AddElement(image);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        //Add table to document    
        pdfDoc.Add(table);
    }
```

Here is what I want to have.
[image: what i want]

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it i made a mistake i create a table of 1 when i should have made it of size 2.

```
    //Table
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
```

and the i added a line break like this in the paragraph like this

```
   Paragraph p = new Paragraph("\nReporte de intervención", font);
```